# How do you create an integer ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am trying to create an array of Arraylists in Java. I have declared it in the following way:

```
ArrayList[][][] arrayQ = new ArrayList[90][13][18];

for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 18; k++) {
      arrayQ[i][j][k] = new ArrayList<int>();
    }  
  } 
}
```

However, adding the `<int>` inside the while loop throws an error (the IDE I'm using unfortunately doesn't give me a very good error message).

What's the proper way to create an integer ArrayList?

Comment: now what if I wanted to use the integer value and pass it to a function that takes an int? because if I try to pass it something like function(arrayQ[i][j][0].get(k), 77) it is passing this as an Integer object. how would I case it to a primitive int?

Comment: Just write `new Integer(77)` instead of the `int` literal.

Comment: No, write `Integer.valueOf(77)`.

Answer (score 10):

Java Collections can only hold objects. `int` is a primitive data type and cannot be held in an `ArrayList` for example. You need to use [Integer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a complete example:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] foo = new ArrayList[3];

foo[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
foo[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
foo[2] = new ArrayList<Integer>();

foo[0].add(123);
foo[0].add(23);
foo[1].add(163);
foo[1].add(23789);
foo[2].add(3);
foo[2].add(2);

for (ArrayList<Integer> mylist: foo) {
  for (int bar : mylist) {
    println(bar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

joschi and Cristian are correct.  Change `new ArrayList<int>()` to `new ArrayList<Integer>()` and you should be fine.

If at all possible, I would recommend using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) as your IDE.  It provides (usually) very specific, detailed, and generally helpful error messages to help you debug your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that an `ArrayList` requires `Objects` - you cannot use primitive types.

You'll need to write `arrayQ[i][j][k] = new ArrayList<Integer>();`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing the non-generic and generic `ArrayLists`.  Your 3D array of `ArrayList` uses the non-generic, but you are trying to assign a generic `ArrayList<int>`.  Try switching one of these to match the other.